# UIBottom Text Field not setting

Tags: ios, swift

I have a label that displays a random emoji, and then I have 4 UIButtons.  Each one will display a random emoji, and one of the 4 will display the same emoji as the one on the label.  Its a matching game.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var faceLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

var randomEmojiNum: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(6) + 1

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    faceLabel.text = genRanNum()
}

func genRanNum() -> String{
    switch randomEmojiNum{
    case 1:  return ""
    case 2:  return ""
    case 3:  return ""
    case 4:  return ""
    case 5:  return ""
    case 6:  return ""
    default: break
    }
    return "Default"
}

func correctAnswerGen() {
    var correct: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(4)
    switch correct{
    case 0: topLeftAnswer.titleLabel?.text = genRanNum()
    case 1: topRightAnswer.titleLabel?.text = genRanNum()
    case 2: bottomRightAnswer.titleLabel?.text = genRanNum()
    case 3: bottomLeftAnswer.titleLabel?.text = genRanNum()
    default: break
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var topLeftAnswer: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var topRightAnswer: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomLeftAnswer: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomRightAnswer: UIButton!
}
```

But every time I run it, it doesn't go as expected. Right now I'm assigning randomly one of the 4 UIButton outlets to be set to the same emoji as the one on the label, however none of the outlets set!

Whenever I run it looks like it is being selected.  None of the buttons ever get set! I have a hunch it has something to do with the outlets being set and me editing the value after they are set. However, if i knew, i wouldn't be asking for help! Haha cheers!

Comment: `switch random` , what is `random` here?

Comment: `correctAnswerGen` - you haven't called/used it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `topLeftAnswer.titleLabel?.text` just use:

```
topLeftAnswer.setTitle("emoji", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I accomplished this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var faceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var topLeftAnswer: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var topRightAnswer: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomLeftAnswer: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomRightAnswer: UIButton!

    var randomEmojiNum: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(6) + 1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        faceLabel.text = genRanNum()
        correctAnswerGen()
    }

    func genRanNum() -> String{
        switch randomEmojiNum{
        case 1:  return ""
        case 2:  return ""
        case 3:  return ""
        case 4:  return ""
        case 5:  return ""
        case 6:  return ""
        default: break
        }
        return "Default"
    }

    func correctAnswerGen() {
        var correct: UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(4)
        switch correct{
        case 0: topLeftAnswer.setTitle(genRanNum(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        case 1: topRightAnswer.setTitle(genRanNum(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        case 2: bottomLeftAnswer.setTitle(genRanNum(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        case 3: bottomRightAnswer.setTitle(genRanNum(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

Update : Edited According to OP requirement.

Comment: its working in the sense that the emoji is now printing on the UIButton however its only printing the correct emoji sometimes and other times its not printing any emoji

Comment: I fixed it! You were passing in "correct" as the parameter for genRanNum, however correct is the random number to pick the UIButton that was printing it, I needed to pass in randomEmojiNum!